# Response times Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using a proxy to make requests to the Google Analytics API. This proxy has a timeout of 30 seconds and I reach this timeout some times. Do you know if it is normal that Google last more than 30 seconds in the response? The biggest request I have contains 4 metrics and 4 dimensions.

Also, I want to ask if there is any way of improving this response times, maybe requesting a lower number of results per page or any other mechanism similar.

Comment: What statistics are you requesting from the api? And what language do you use?

Comment: (Anecdotally) I have not encountered problems with response times. Maybe you hit some API limit when you do too many queries per second (there are cap specified here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas, although this should result in errors rather than timeouts).

Comment: I'm using Ruby and I'm requesting: "pageviews", "entrances", "bounceRate", "exitRate", "pagePath" and three custom dimensions. And I don't think I'm reaching the queries per second limits because I usually get an error when I reach any limit from Google.

Comment: It could be that the custom dimensions you're talking about are taking a little bit more time to calculate on the side of Google. You could try to request everything on it's own and see what the response time is. If the custom dimensions take a lot of time, it could be better to split the requests.

Comment: The problem is that I need all this information unaggregated, so I can't split this request into smaller ones. Is there any other advice to make this request faster?

Comment: Have you tried to make more requests with shorter date ranges? You can make 10 requests per second for a given View (profile), so you might just try putting more queries in the pipe.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I think this can help but If I split in shorter date ranges I create a little discrepancy when I join the response of all the requests, so I prefer to use this as a last option in order to avoid insert noise in the final result. Any other idea?